# How do I get all the arguments specified on the command line in a list?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm creating a function in config:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--type', action = 'append', default = [])
    parser.addoption('--input', default='')
    parser.addoption('--output', default='')
    .......
```

There are many such options. How can I get their arguments specified on the command line all at once? For example, in a list (format is not important).

How to implement such that I don't need to write a separate line to get an argument for each parameter? Because now it looks like this:

```
type = request.config.getoption("type")
input = request.config.getoption("input")
output = request.config.getoption("output")
.........
```

`request.config` has an `args` method, but it contains only the path of the file to be launched.

Comment: As a result, I have a lot of options and prescribing the command to get an argument for each option, the code looks terrible.

Comment: `sys.argv` contains all the command line arguments.

Comment: You could loop over the keys and store the result in a dictionary

Comment: ** `sys.argv` contains all the command line arguments** - this is his problem, I will have to separate the values from the parameters and remove unnecessary values from the list, for example, the code launch path

Comment: Can I sort through the keys using `request.config` or another method?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, the following code:

```
    args = [arg[2:] for arg in sys.argv if '--' in arg[:2] and '--t' not in arg]
    for arg in args:
         val_arg = request.config.getoption(arg)
```

But you can't get the default values this way. And the method itself is not particularly good.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you need to get all *passed* options:

The [`request.config`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#config) object has [`invocation_params`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.Config.invocation_params) attribute which stores:

> The parameters with which pytest was invoked.

For example, if pytest was called like this:

```
$ pytest tests/test_1.py tests/test_2.py --maxfail=1 --cache-clear --custom-opt2=222 --custom-opt4=444 -rP
```

where

- `tests/*.py` are the positional `file_or_dir` tests
- `--maxfail=1`, `--cache-clear`, `-rP` are built-in pytest options
- `--custom-opt1`, `--custom-opt2` are custom options added using [`pytest_addoption`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=addoption#std-hook-pytest_addoption) hook

then reading `invocation_params.args`:

```
from pytest import FixtureRequest

def test_passed_options(request: FixtureRequest):
    print(request.config.invocation_params.args)
```

would give a Tuple of:

```
('tests/test_1.py', 'tests/test_2.py', '--maxfail=1', '--cache-clear', '--custom-opt2=222', '--custom-opt4=444', '-rP')
```

To get *just* the options and their values (for non-flag-like options), you can filter out the positional args:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
from pytest import FixtureRequest

def test_passed_options(request: FixtureRequest):
    all_args = request.config.invocation_params.args
    all_opts = filterfalse(lambda arg: not arg.startswith("-"), all_args)
    for opt in all_opts:
        print(opt)
```

```
--maxfail=1
--cache-clear
--custom-opt2=222
--custom-opt4=444
-rP
```

Now it's just a matter of splitting on `=` to get option names and their values:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
from pytest import FixtureRequest

def test_passed_options(request: FixtureRequest):
    all_args = request.config.invocation_params.args
    all_opts = {}
    for opt in filterfalse(lambda arg: not arg.startswith("-"), all_args):
        opt_name, _, opt_val = opt.partition("=")
        all_opts[opt_name] = opt_val or True
    print(all_opts)
```

```
{'--cache-clear': True,
 '--custom-opt2': '222',
 '--custom-opt4': '444',
 '--maxfail': '1',
 '-rP': True}
```

#### If you need to get all *available* options and their default values:

The [`request.config`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=pytest_addoption#config) object has [`option`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=pytest_addoption#pytest.Config.option) attribute which stores all the *available* command line options along with their default values. It's essentially an [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object, so you can just apply [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) on it get a dict of all the *available* options.

```
from pytest import FixtureRequest

def test_available_options(request: FixtureRequest):
    all_opts = vars(request.config.option)
    print(all_opts)
```

```
{'assertmode': 'rewrite',
 'basetemp': None,
 'cacheclear': True,
 'cacheshow': None,
 'capture': 'fd',
 ...
 'custom_opt1': 'default_opt1_val',
 'custom_opt2': '222',
 'custom_opt3': 'default_opt3_val',
 'custom_opt4': '444',
 'debug': None,
 ...
 'file_or_dir': ['tests/test_1.py', 'tests/test_2.py'],
 ...
 'verbose': 0,
 'version': 0,
 'xmlpath': None}
```

Note, this is actually tricky to use because it includes *both* the built-in pytest options *and* your custom options. But, it *does* include the default values of all the options, if that's what your after.

If it's possible to prefix your custom options with an identifier

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--custom-opt1", action="store", default="default_opt1_val")
    parser.addoption("--custom-opt2", action="store", default="default_opt2_val")
    parser.addoption("--custom-opt3", action="store", default="default_opt3_val")
    parser.addoption("--custom-opt4", action="store", default="default_opt4_val")
```

Then, you can filter only your custom options from the `Namespace` object:

```
$ pytest tests/test_1.py tests/test_2.py --maxfail=1 --cache-clear --custom-opt2=222 --custom-opt4=444 -rP
```

```
from pytest import FixtureRequest

def test_available_options(request: FixtureRequest):
    all_opts = vars(request.config.option)
    my_opts = {}
    for opt in filterfalse(lambda opt: not opt.startswith("custom"), all_opts.keys()):
        my_opts[opt] = all_opts[opt]
    print(my_opts)
```

```
{'custom_opt1': 'default_opt1_val',
 'custom_opt2': '222',
 'custom_opt3': 'default_opt3_val',
 'custom_opt4': '444'}
```